# Add ImageView dynamically to View

Tags: android, imageview, android-view, dynamically-generated

I am making an Android game which uses the View class and I am not using an XML-layout.

All my images are drawn with canvas. Now my problem is the I cannot use a bitmap.

I am trying to add an ImageView dynamically to my View class, to use the touchable event.

Why dynamically? Because I could not use XML-layout.
Here is my code:

```
package com.example.poolmaster;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private int cuePosx, cuePosy;

    int cueHeight, cueWeight;
    double rotatingAngle;
    int height;
    int wwidth;
    int cueHeight2, cueWeight2;
    Bitmap table, stick, raise;

    ImageView button = new ImageView(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
        rotatingAngle = 0;
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        wwidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        cueHeight2 = height / 2;
        cueWeight2 = wwidth / 2;
        System.out.println("**************************************");
        System.out.println("height " + height);
        System.out.println("weight" + wwidth);
        System.out.println("**************************************");
      
        // Set generic layout parameters
        GamePlay custom = new GamePlay(this);

        setContentView(custom);
       // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            // cuePosy += 10;
            // System.out.println("xCORDİNATES!!!! " +ev.getX());
            // System.out.println("yCORDİNATES!!!! " +ev.getY());
            rotatingAngle=getAngle(ev.getX(), ev.getY());
            System.out.println("Angle " +rotatingAngle);
        }
        if (ev.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            System.out.println("****************** ACTİON DOWN ****************");
            // cueHeight2 += 10;
            // cueWeight2 += 20;
            // cuePosy = 320;
        }
        if (ev.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            System.out.println("****************** ACTİON DOWN ****************");
            // cueHeight2 -= 10;
            // cueWeight2 -= 20;
            // cuePosy = 320;
        }
        return true;
    }
    private double getAngle(double xTouch, double yTouch) {
        double theta;
        
        theta = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(height / 2 - yTouch, xTouch - wwidth / 2));
        return theta;
    }
    
    public class GamePlay extends View {
        public GamePlay(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            table = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bg);
            table = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(table, wwidth, height, true);
            stick = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.stick);

            raise = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.raise);
            cueHeight = stick.getHeight();
            System.out.println("ıstaka " + cueHeight);
            cueWeight = stick.getWidth();
            cuePosx = wwidth / 2;
            cuePosy = height - cueHeight - 180;
        }
        @SuppressLint({ "DrawAllocation", "DrawAllocation" })
        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.setTranslate(cueWeight2, cueHeight2);
            matrix.postRotate((float)rotatingAngle, cueWeight2, cueHeight2); // anti-clockwise by 90 degrees
               
            // create a new bitmap from the original using the matrix to transform the result
            Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(stick, 0, 0, stick.getWidth(), stick.getHeight(), matrix, false);
               
            canvas.save(); // Save the position of the canvas.
            canvas.restore();
               
            // Rotate the canvas.
            canvas.drawBitmap(table, 0, 0, null); // Draw the ball on the rotated canvas.
            canvas.drawBitmap(stick, matrix, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(raise, 0, 0, null);
            invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If my answer is helping you then please accept it, so it will help others also.

Answer (score 4):

### This is for adding imageview to a layout where Activity class is extended

```
   LinearLayout lL = findViewById(R.id.xmlfile_layout_id);

   ImageView imgView = new ImageView(context); 

   imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   lL.addView(imgView);
```

### This is for adding imageview to a canvas where View class is extended

Initially, you cannot place any imageview, edit text or buttons using canvas. Instead, you have to draw it. So create a custom layout and draw that layout with canvas

Try this, It might help you. in `onDraw(..)`

```
   LinearLayout lL = new LinearLayout(context);

   ImageView imgView = new ImageView(context); 

   imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   lL.addView(imgView);

    lL.measure(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    lL.layout(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

    // placing the edit text at specific co-ordinates:
    //canvas.translate(0, 0);
    layout.draw(canvas);
```

And take a look at this another example :  [Click here](http://www.kellbot.com/2009/06/android-hello-circle/)

It gives another way of adding views

Comment: yeah you can add this image to any view .

Comment: what is layout object here(layout.draw)? you mean lL object?

Comment: unfortunately it gave exception

Comment: ok now there is no exception but there is no image on the screen

Comment: Now remove this line : lL.draw(canvas); I'm not sure, try it

Comment: when lL.addView(imgView); it gave exception 12-22 14:01:16.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1520): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: what happens if you remove  lL.addView(imgView); this line

Comment: if remove this there is no exception but there is no image on the screen

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for that.

For Create ImageView Dynamically

```
ImageView mImgView1 = new ImageView(this);
```

For Add into your View write below code before `setContentView(custom);` (If GamePlay is your View Class)

```
custom.add(mImgView1);
```

Comment: yes gameplay is my View class(public void GamePlay extends View) write like this.however there is no method like custom.add

Comment: @TunçDoğan Then please googling about that because i don't know about how to add add() method in custom view class.