# Add imageview dynamically to existing view

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater

I'm developing an app which on start up will show a pre-defined layout like **Image(1)** in below screenshot.

Now onclick of a button, I want to dynamically add another view like **Image(2)** in below screenshot to existing view resulting into some like **Image(3)** in below screenshot.

If onclick is clicked again, **Image(2)** will be added to existing view resulting into something like **Image(4)**.

How do I achieve this?
 By searching, I found that it required something like `LayoutInflater.addView()` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view) or `LinearLayout.addView()` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002996/add-imageview-dynamically-to-view).

But I don't know what exactly to use in my case.
Also, I'm not trying to add **just a single view** on button click, but a group of certain views like imageview, 2 textviews,etc. as shown in **Image(2)**.

Any help appreciated.

---

[image: screenshot]

---

### Edit 1:

I tried something like this:
**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello_world" />
        </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:onClick="addViews"
        android:text="Add" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    LinearLayout main;
    int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
    }

    public void addViews(View view) {
        LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        count++;
        btn.setText("Hello World : " + count);
        main.addView(btn, count);
    }
}
```

It yields something like this:

[image: screenshot]

**Now, how do I recognize which button is clicked?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a lot of things to get that working, but the best approach could be using `ListView` and `ArrayAdapter`

Create a class that extends `ArrayAdapter<Integer>`. There, create a `interface` to create a Listener.

```
public interface OnListButtonItemClickedListener{

   public int onListButonItemClicked(int position);

}
```

Define a private `OnListButtonItemClickedListener` on your `ArrayAdapter`, and create a public setter.

```
private OnListButtonItemClickedListener listener;

public void setOnListButtonItemClickedListener(OnListButtonItemClickedListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

Define a button inside a Layout in XML. Something like this will do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dip" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Create a inner `ViewHolder` class inside your `ArrayAdapter` class like this:

```
private class ViewHolder{
    public Button b;
}
```

Override `getView` and create something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ViewHandler vh;
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.your_layout, null);
            vh = new ViewHolder();
            vh.b = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            convertView.setTag(vh);
        } else {
            vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        vh.b.setText(String.valueOf(getItem(i).intValue()));
        vh.b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){
                if (listener != null){
                    listener.onListButonItemClicked(getItem(position).intValue());
                }
            }

        });
        return convertView;
    }
```

Set the adapter to a ListView, and when you want to add a new one, just do this:

```
adapter.add(i);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks. What is **i** in `vh.b.setText(String.valueOf(getItem(i).intValue()));` ??

Answer (score 5):

So, you can inflate a view from an XML layout from an `Activity` like this

`View v = View.inflate(this, R.layout.whatever, null);`

and then you can add it to your `LinearLayout` like this:

`linearLayout.addView(v);`

If you want to access the inner views in your items, you can do it like this:

`TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);`

So, you have to define that group of views in a XML layout, inflate it, manipulate its views as you need, and then add it to your `LinearLayout`.

Note that you'll need your LinearLayout orientation to be vertical or it won't work as you need.

Comment: Please check my other answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this fits whatever your app's purpose is, but try using a `ListView` with an `ArrayAdapter`. You will begin with an empty `ListView`, as defined in XML, then add items to a connected `ArrayAdapter` in code. Each time the button is pressed, you can add an image into the `ArrayAdapter` and call `.notifyDataSetChanged()`. This should stack them just as shown in your images above. You can also use a secondary `LinearLayout` to group items.

EDIT:

To determine which button is clicked you simply reference the `View` passed to your `addViews(View v)` method. You can either switch on the id:

```
public void addViews(View v){
    int id = v.getId();
    switch(id){
        case R.id.id1:
            //do something
        case R.id.id2:
            //do something
     }
}
```

Or you can get the text from the button in a similar manner by using:

```
public void addViews(View v){
    Button b = (Button)v; //make sure you know that it will be a button
    String s = b.getText().toString();
    switch(s){
        case "test case 1":
            //do something
        case "test case 2":
            //do something
    }
}
```

If you aren't sure how many buttons there will be, I would suggest using the strings method. If the buttons won't have names that are convenient to parse in this manner, store references to the buttons as keys in a HashMap and use a String as the value. You can then plug in the button, get the string and do whatever is needed.

Comment: But each row of listview is composite layout itself.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this

- Create a custom view that extends LinearLayout, orientation: vertical.
- Create another custom view, this view will be the "row". This view is the container of the image, text in bold and text below.
- In the first custom view that extends linearLayout, you can addView(View v) and pass the other custom view, the row.

Am I clear? It is something similar that adapter and listview works.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Will surely try and will let you know. Thanks !