# Show Multiple ImageViews Dynamically in Relative Layout Android

Tags: android, imageview, android-relativelayout

I am working in An Android App
in which 
Relative layout is

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mymainlayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    >

</RelativeLayout>
```

my problem is I am unable to Draw all ImageViews programatically in this Relative Layout it is showing only one image.
Here is my code

```
    for (int i = 0; i < realAnswer; i++) {

        arrayofImages[i] = new ImageView(this);
        arrayofImages[i].setImageResource(imageId[imageNumber]);
        arrayofImages[i].setId(i);
        if(i!=0)
        {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF,  arrayofImages[i-1].getId());
        //arrayofImages[i].setLayoutParams(params);
        nn.addView(arrayofImages[i],params);
        }
    else
        {
            nn.addView(arrayofImages[i]);
        }

    }
```

here nn is my main layout

any help Please   ???

Comment: You should dynamically add Image views, see [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942486/add-imageview-dynamically-to-existing-view

Comment: What do you want to achieve, exactly?

Comment: i want to show 10 images in layout. earliar i have used linear layout but it was showing only 7 images maximum. the weight sum was 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working fine except for

```
 params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF,  arrayofImages[i-1].getId());
```

**RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF** its keep on setting image to the left and you are unable to see it.

Replace above code with

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,
                        arrayofImages[i - 1].getId());
```

This will display images in horizontal direction.

Updated your for loop like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            arrayofImages[i] = new ImageView(this);
            arrayofImages[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            arrayofImages[i].setId(i);
            if (i != 0) {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,
                        arrayofImages[i - 1].getId());
                // arrayofImages[i].setLayoutParams(params);
                nn.addView(arrayofImages[i], params);
            } else {
                nn.addView(arrayofImages[i]);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `RelativeLayout` just to hold the `imageview`s which you are adding dymanically, then use `LinearLayout`. That will solve your problem.

Comment: i have used linear layout earliar but problem is with  linearlayout is that it is not showing all 10 images it is showing only maximum 7 images. not more than seven. the weight sum was 10

Comment: @NoamanAkram you have to use scroll view to show more then 10 images . scroll view will have another linear with will have orientation aswell

Answer (score 0):

have a look this may be useful to you:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, imageArra);
      ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
      myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
      myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }

    private int imageArra[] = { R.drawable.gallery_photo_1, R.drawable.gallery_photo_2,
     R.drawable.gallery_photo_3, R.drawable.gallery_photo_5,
     R.drawable.gallery_photo_6, R.drawable.gallery_photo_7,
     R.drawable.gallery_photo_8, R.drawable.ic_launcher };

   }
}
```

and ViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

 Activity activity;
 int imageArray[];

 public ViewPagerAdapter(Activity act, int[] imgArra) {
 imageArray = imgArra;
 activity = act;
 }

 public int getCount() {
  return imageArray.length;
 }

 public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
   ImageView view = new ImageView(activity);
   view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
  view.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
  view.setBackgroundResource(imageArray[position]);
  ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
 return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
 ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
 return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
}

 @Override
 public Parcelable saveState() {
  return null;
 }
}
```

xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/myfivepanelpager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >

</ImageView>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```